# Filling in the arms

Tags: armature

I am trying to fill in the arms of my creature, but I can't seem to do it.  Was there a mistake I did while make the creature? I am not sure why the arms and legs are not hollow 3D forms.  I attached a screen shot of what it looks like. 
[image]

Comment: From your screenshot I'm guessing your model is very [non-manifold](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599). This would likely cause a lot of tools to apparently not work, as their requirements for surrounding topology are not met. Without a .blend it'll be hard to say precisely where and how the geometry is non-manifold.

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like the normals of the arms of your creature are inside out. Every Face has 2 sides, one side is the side for the outer face, which you see, the other side is the inner face which you should not see. The inner face has slighty different shading, it looks a little darker and kind of blueish.
   To change this, you should select the face you want to change in Edit Mode, then press "Space" and type in "Flip Normals", then click the command "Flip Normals". It will then flip the faces around.
2. Basically it looks like there would be a triangle face at the "hand" and the rest could be quads. Just go in Edit Mode, Vertex Select, then select the 3 vertices on the very end of the arm which are on the upper side of it, then press "F" to fill them with a face. Continue by selecting the 4 vertices next to it (2 up 2 down) where the right 2 vertices should be at the edge of the face you just created when speaking of the right arm. Press "F" to fill again, then just continue like that.